# Spring Cloud Gateway bottleneck at network, requests taking time to reach the destination server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

We are using Spring cloud Gateway which uses Netty dependency running on Apache Tomcat, Linux server. API gateway using Redis for token mechanism.
We observed that requests coming from client are forwared from API gateway server which are recieved after 8-12 secs at other application server.

We tested the same API direct from the gateway application server via two ways

1. through API gateway
2. through direct curl

and checked their response received time on the other microservice application server. We found that we received response within mini-sec in 2nd case, and in 1st case it takes a lag of 8-12 sec. **API Gateway is slow at the network level** not at the application level since we saw the gateway response logs within a sec after gateway logic

API gateway sent the request forward at 14:09:34
[image: API gateway sent the request forward at 14:09:34]

App server received it at 14:09:50
[image: App server received it at 14:09:50]

Here, API gateway evaluates everything on the expected time and gives responses but received after a lag of few seconds in other microservice.

API Gateway used - Spring cloud API Gateway which uses Netty dependency
Server - Apache Tomcat, Linux

Comment: it is a guessing game from the outside. it could be something like the web-client used in cloud-gateway using a connection pool and the connections are dead but it doesn't know --> it waits until a timeout, creates a new connection and then it works. This can happen e.g. if there is something in between like a load-balancer which kills the connection or the receiving system has lower values for keep alive than your cloud gateway.